# Find all meshes that use a specific material

Tags: materials

Is there a way to find meshes that use a specific material?

I have duplicated material and it appears that some mesh using those duplicated materials even if I don't find any in the Outliner list.

I know some materials are not used because there is a "0" next to the material's names.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select drop down in the viewport to select > select by > material

Comment: it does not work if not in edit mode

Comment: You should be able to use the select menu in object mode, are you trying to do this in edit mode or object mode?

Comment: object mode. 2.79 don't have Select > Select By... Tried with all mesh selected and none selected.